# How to extract images from a Text in python (regex)

Tags: python, regex, text, extract

Let's say we have text within which images are stored in the form:

```
some text File:image1.extension some text File:image2.extension
```

How can I extract all the images from the text in python?

I tried

```
re.findall('File:(.+?\.(jpe?g|svg|png|gif))', text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

But it's not doing the job.

https://regex101.com/r/PLKREz/3

How can I do it in Python?

Comment: provide a larger example of some text to extract strings from.

Comment: Try `regex = r"\[\[File:(\S+\.(?:jpe?g|png|[tg]iff?|svg))"` but in Python, not on the regex101.com.

Comment: When does it fail?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex is what i was looking for. thank you

Comment: Great, I posted with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If your raw string, `raw_string`, is something like:

```
File:image1.png
File:image1.pdf
File:image1.gif
File:image1.txt
File:image1.jpeg
```

Then you can use the regex `File:.+?\.((pdf)|(png)|(gif)|(jpeg))`. In Python that becomes:

```
re.findall(r'File:.+?\.((pdf)|(png)|(gif)|(jpeg))', raw_string)
```

This will only retrieve the file formats that you specify inside the outer parenthesis, seperated by the `|`operator, in this example everything but the file ending in `.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
regex = r"\[\[File:(\S+\.(?:jpe?g|png|[tg]iff?|svg))"
```

The pattern matches

- `\[\[File:` - two `[`s and a `File:` substring
- `(\S+\.(?:jpe?g|png|[tg]iff?|svg))` - captures into Group 1 (and thus, only returns this subtext as a result of `re.findall`)

  - `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(?:jpe?g|png|[tg]iff?|svg)`  - one of the alternatives inside the non-capturing group (so that it was not output in the `re.findall` results): either `jpeg`, `jpg`, `tiff`, `gif` (and even `giff`), or `svg`.